# Losing connection when watching flash videos

Tags: flash, internet-connection

Whenever I play a flash video on my browser (whichever I use, Chrome, Firefox or IE), there's a risk that I lose my Internet connection. I know it's limited to my computer only as my roommates are unaffected. I'm the only one that loses connection. Using Internet Explorer's diagnosis tool always repairs the connection, but it's annoying as hell.

My OS is Windows XP, if that matters.

Anyone knows what may be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a wireless connection (e.g. for a laptop)?

Comment: @JoshKing: No. My roommates are, but I am not.

Comment: haha well I am officially out of ideas. Personally if it were me I would opt for a reformat of my PC (but I do this every few months anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating flash player, your browser and any other misc Windows updates (you never know).

Also try a different browser (Firefox or Chrome will be a good start).;

Comment: It happens on Chrome and Firefox. It's unlikely that it's due to out of date flash or browser, since it has been happening for several months now.

Comment: @Borror0 might pay to try an uninstall of flash and downloading the latest version from Adobe. Also what service pack for XP are you on?

Comment: Service Pack 3. I updated Adobe today, but I could try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a problem with your ISP provider(frequent disconnection) and this normally happens with wireless as 'jost king' said. Try raising a complaint and see what happens. Ofcourse it's not a solution to the problem but could be as it happened to be many times with wired and raising a complaint solves the issue.

Comment: If it's a problem with my ISP, why am I the only one affected? MY roommate should lose connection at the same time as I, or at least once in a while, no?

Comment: Are you sharing internet connection with your roommates?

Comment: If sharing, are you using HUB or switch?

Comment: @user51737: Yes. I'm sharing my Internet with my roommates, which is why I doubt it's my ISP's fault. If it was a problem on my ISP's side, shouldn't it affect them too? Using the 2701HG-G modem given by my ISP. (Hopefully, that answers the second question.)